# GoMap - display map in hidden div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the goMap jQuery plugin for displaying my maps, and would like to have the map hidden and display it on click. However, the map isn't displayed correctly.

In another thread I found I need to fire `google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');` to refresh the map, but for some reason this doesn't work in my code.

Can anyone help me with this? Thanks

```
<a class="showmap" href="#">Show map</a>
<div id="map" style="height: 400px; width: 400px;"> </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $("#map").goMap({
        latitude: 56.948813,
        longitude: 24.104004,
        zoom: 6
    });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#map").hide();
    $('.showmap').click(function() {
        $("#map").slideToggle();
        google.maps.event.trigger($.goMap.mapId, 'resize');
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use

`google.maps.event.trigger($.goMap.map, 'resize');`

I think you need to trigger resize after the div containing the map is fully revealed.

```
$('#map').slideToggle('slow', function() {
  google.maps.event.trigger($.goMap.map, 'resize');
});
```

Comment: Nice question, and good answer. It also solves google maps in a tab. For ex. I've succesfully used google.maps.event.trigger($.goMap.map, 'resize'); in onSwitch callback of tabbed content https://github.com/elboletaire/tabbedcontent (i like using this plugin to make tabs instead of loading the heavier jQuery UI)